# Cannot install Mercurial on Eclipse Juno

Tags: eclipse, mercurial

Attempting to install Mercurial on Eclipse Java EE IDE Juno from 
http://cbes.javaforge.com/update in the Install new software...

but,

"Cannot complete the install because one or more required items could not be found. Software being installed: codeBeamer Eclipse Studio (with Mylyn) 3.1.0.v201011161842 (org.codebeamer.eclipse.mylyn_feature.feature.group 3.1.0.v201011161842) Missing requirement: codeBeamer Eclipse Studio (with Mylyn) 3.1.0.v201011161842 (org.codebeamer.eclipse.mylyn_feature.feature.group 3.1.0.v201011161842) requires 'org.eclipse.mylyn_feature.feature.group 3.3.0' but it could not be found

I tried on Windows 7_64 and ubuntu 12.04_64. I even installed mylyn using the latest stable releases from http://download.eclipse.org/mylyn/releases/latest

Any Ideas?

Already browsed web and this site.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could also try [the update URL from the Google Code repository](http://mercurialeclipse.eclipselabs.org.codespot.com/hg.wiki/update_site/stable) instead, which installs only MercurialEclipse.

Comment: I am glad it helped. Could you cast a give my answer a vote please :)?

Comment: newbie here. Thanks for the tip.

Answer (score 1):

+1 to installing from Google Code Repository.

Initially Eclipse wouldn't start because of problems with the older version of the plugin so to get past this simply removed the jar com.vectrace.MercurialEclipse_1.9.1.v201111302231.jar from the Eclipse plugins directory then uninstalled the existing plugin and re-installed from the link in [smooth reggae](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11443538/15168)'s post.
All seems good so far.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is, that the codeBeamer Eclipse Studio requires an older version of Mylyn (3.3.0), which isn't available for Juno. 
But AFAIK you don't need the whole CBES, if you only need the Mercurial features. Try to select only MercurialEclipse, it should also be available in that update site.